# "Рисунки выполнены черно-белыми" - так говорят?

Tags: стилистика, управление

Скажите, пожалуйста, является ли грамматически и стилистически корректным предложение

***Все рисунки должны быть выполнены черно-белыми либо в градациях серого, цветные рисунки не принимаются***

или же стоит убрать слово "выполнены"?

Т. е. допускает ли глагол *выполнить* управления прилагательным в творительном падеже: *выполнить что-л. каким-л.*?
Если нет, то приемлем ли вариант, когда из исходного предложения выкинуто слово "выполнены": 
*Все рисунки должны быть черно-белыми либо в градациях серого...*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грамматически предложение верно, стиль его формальный. Выражение "выполнен таким-то" или "выполнен в виде" широко употребляется, в частности, в формулах изобретений, которые имеют строгий юридический смысл. Например, при раскрытии отличий объекта изобретения встречаются выражения типа "устройство по п.1, отличающееся тем, что элемент такой-то *выполнен открывающимся* внутрь","*выполнен съёмным*" и т. п. Проблем с управлением падежом быть не должно, ср. "рождён мёртвым", "оставлен нетронутым" (выполнен таким = выполнен так, что в результате выполнения является таким). Другое дело, что понятие "чёрно-белый" в противопоставлении "цветному" (напр. в  телевидении) включает в себя и случай с градациями серого, из-за чего вариант без градаций (только чёрное и белое) обычно отдельно оговаривают как "факсимильный". Но в данном случае и без этой строгости ясно, что имеется в виду. Отбрасывание слова "выполнен" грамматически возможно, но не улучшает стиля (звучит излишне категорично, почти угрожающе). Я бы остановился на исходном варианте.

Answer (score 1):

Использование в вашем примере можно считать допустимым. Но только потому, что он не привносит двусмысленности. Творительный падеж в первую голову отвечает на вопрос "Кем?", а не "Каким?". Если этой проблемы в понимании не возникает, можно пользоваться.

Аналогии здесь очень опасная вещь. Помните знаменитое **Полковник наш рожден был хватом**? У современного читателя может возникнуть вопрос, хват - это отец полковника? Или, того хуже,  инструмент, которым его, бедного, из материнской утробы вытаскивали? Вот в этом таится большая опасность аналогий вообще и творительного падежа в частности.

Здесь, по счастью, такого не возникает, хотя в целом фраза кажется стилистически неряшливой. Более привычное и профессиональное - **"выполнены в черно-белой технике"**

Comment: Вообще-то "выполнены черно-белыми" тоже можно понять как приписывание авторства неким авторам окраса зебры. Лучше не пользовать, имхо.